# How to remove or uninstall an orphaned service?

Tags: windows, installation, service

There are times when Windows Services are installed and for various reasons, that hopefully are not important to the answer, the service no longer has the installer *attached* to it. Therefore, this particular service shows up in the list of Services, but cannot be uninstalled through normal practices.

In situations like this, how does one go about *manually* removing the orphaned service?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Using sc.exe from system32 dir:

```
sc delete <service_name>
```

(be sure to stop the service first)

Comment: And then (and only then) remove files (executable or otherwise).

Comment: One comment, if your service has a space in the name, you should use: sc delete "<service name>"

Comment: What if there was an uninstaller and it removed the files, but did not remove the service?

Comment: Never mind - It seems to work. BTW, the Service Name is not the same as the display name. You have to right click the service and select properties to see the actual name.