# Techniques for removing orphaned programs in Windows

Tags: windows, windows-registry

Inspired by the questions on [removing orphaned services](https://serverfault.com/questions/2514/how-can-i-remove-uninstall-an-orphaned-service) and [force-removing windows services](https://serverfault.com/questions/11920/force-removing-windows-services), what techniques do you use to remove traces of an application from Windows?  Traces include things like

- Leftover files in system folders / Program Files
- Registry info
- Bad user settings

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One tool I have had good luck with is the [Windows Installer Cleanup Tool](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/290301).

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes once you've tried the uninstallers and the cleanup tools, your left with on option, delete the files, and trawl the registry to remove keys.

**Editing your registry can harm you pc, backup etc...**

The most common places to find applicaiton settings are :

- HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE.
- HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE.
- HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\ CURRENTCONTROLSET\SERVICES

In particular your going to want to look at H`KEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\MICROSOFT\CURRENTVERSION\RUN`, this is where the startup information is stored, so any apps that start on boot will be in here.

Answer (score 0):

I uninstall using [Revo Uninstaller](http://www.revouninstaller.com/). It's wonderful and free.
I remove trash using [CCleaner](http://www.ccleaner.com/).

And finally, I use [Process Explorer](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896653.aspx) and [AutoRuns](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb963902.aspx) to find any zombie autostarting and running in background.